# The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the extension configuration

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, azure, web-hosting

Well this morning I woke up to see that my site hosted on Windows Azure was producing 50X errors and in general being incredibly slow (up to 60 seconds response time).

Now after looking through the DetailedErrors folder I see that the error received is:

`HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found
The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the extension configuration. If the page is a script, add a handler. If the file should be downloaded, add a MIME map.`

I tried creating a new test website and host it and guess what? I receive the exact same error here as well.

What could be causing this?

Comment: Looks like your provider is having problems. Contact them.

Comment: @Oscar
I see. However it is Windows Azure and apparently my current plan does not provide technical support.
Anyone runnign on Windows Azure who knows what to do?

Comment: @DND 2013 Professional - I just installed it a few days ago.

Answer (score 0):

I found this for you.

There were more errors related to local machine below these errors.I looked up the net and after some digging figured out the solution to the problem:

Run Visual Studio 2008 Command Prompt as “Administrator”.
Navigate to C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.0\Windows Communication Foundation.
Run this command servicemodelreg –i.

for more [info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732012.aspx)